# Cannot access identity claims in custom authorize attribute in MVC application

Tags: identityserver3, authorize-attribute

I am trying to do POC of switching from forms authentication in existing MVC 4 application to claims-based one, but cannot get custom authorize attribute working - have infinite redirect loop ending with known 'bad request' issue because of total cookie size...
And the reason - there is no authenticated identity (and correct Claims collection) in attribute context as I see it in debug despite I see successfully created identity with expected claims collection in SecurityTokenValidated handler.

So, it seems like it is somehow *lost* after OIDC middleware process it, and not unavailable in attribute context, therefore I cannot further check for 'role' claim.

Maybe I am missing something?

My OWIN Startup:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = "sub";
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
        });

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            //AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active, // ? https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/1963
            Authority = OAuthServerUrl,
            ClientId = "my_app",
            RedirectUri = MyAppUrl,
            ResponseType = "id_token token", //notice, if response type 'token' is requested, IdentityServer stops including the claims in the identity token, though we could set alwaysInclude=true for some scope claims (ex. for role)
            Scope = "openid profile roles",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = MyAppUrl,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = n =>
                {
                    var id = n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity;
                    //n.OwinContext.Authentication.SignIn(id);
                    //tried SignIn() explicitly, and even setting HttpContext.Current.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal to n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity, but without luck 
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var result =
                            await n.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                        var idToken = result?.Identity.Claims.GetValue("id_token");
                        if (idToken != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idToken;
                        }
                    }

                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

My custom attribute inherited from System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class ClaimsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        //var owinContext = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // 403 we know who you are, but you haven't been granted access
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        else
        {
            // 401 who are you? go login and then try again
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

where filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity (also tried HttpContext.Current.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal) has Claims collection with single 'name' claim from LOCAL AUTHORITY issuer (default one?).
I also modified Web.config to disable forms auth:

```
<authentication mode="None">
...
<membership>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="999" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="3" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="Audit" />
            <!--<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="999" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="3" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="Audit" />-->
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="Audit" />
            <!--<add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="Audit" />-->
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
    <roleManager enabled="false">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="Audit" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <add applicationName="Audit" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            <!--<add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="Audit" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />-->
            <!--<add applicationName="MyApp" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />-->
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
...
<handlers>
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
<remove name="RoleManager" />
```

**UPDATE 1:** I've migrated app from MVC 4 to the latest MVC 5 hoping it is MVC 4 related issue, but, unfortunately, no difference. Apparently, something wrong with my client application/configuration.

Comment: What's the value of `MyAppUrl`, and what kind of auth is configured for that endpoint..?

Comment: @JohnKorsnes, MyAppUrl is `http://localhost/Audit/`, and i use implicit flow  in client configuration in idsrv3 (if I got the question correctly), i also updated description to mention that upgrade to MVC 5 didn't help..

Comment: Do you have a any route mapped to `/audit` , for instance a `AuditController` ? If yes, do you have any `[Authorization]` filters/attributes running for this route?

Comment: @JohnKorsnes Hmm, no, I checked routes once again. And, actually, /Audit is just a web application under local IIS web site.
I also checked Global.asax.cs once again - no suspicious global handlers or filters etc, mostly logging, localization, IoC container stuff, nothing that could interfere with auth processing in asp.net.

Comment: Check that your're not inheriting web.configs containing any auth modules as well. Physically on disk, they're inherited recursively folder for folder down to root.

Comment: @JohnKorsnes Sorry for late answer...Yes, I checked this - no web.config inheritance. Moreover, I used HttpApplication.Modules to clearly see all loaded modules; I additionally removed WindowsAuthentication, DefaultAuthentication, AnonymousIdentification and Profile ones, so that no auth related modules now for sure. But unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Try to remove your custom stuff:

1 - your notifications. Don't see why you would want to trigger a signin in neither of `SecurityTokenValidated` (this is post login) nor `RedirectToIdProvider` (not for even for logout).

2 - just use the Authorize attribute. It works.

Comment: @blackened 4 years later I'm stuck on an identical issue...
A custom authorization attribute doesn't seem to pickup on any modifications of Context.User occurring in SecurityTokenValidated ..
Any chance of you remembering if / how you fixed it ?